# Using import statement in an internal module

Tags: typescript

I have an internal module that declares a module as a string:

```
declare module "sequelize" {
  // export = ...
}
```

I want to use that "sequelize" module in another declarations file. Something like this:

```
/// <reference path="sequelize/sequelize.d.ts" />

declare module Orm {
  import Sequelize = require("sequelize");

  interface Models {
    item: Sequelize.Model<{}, {}>;
  }
}
```

But when I do that, I get `typings/orm.d.ts(4,30): error TS1147: Import declarations in a namespace cannot reference a module.`

If I move the import statement outside, the file becomes an external module and I start having all sorts of errors like `error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Orm'.`

Is there a way to achieve what I want **without** having to do two declarations in `sequelize.d.ts` like this:

```
declare module Sequelize {
  // export = ...
}

declare module "sequelize" {
  export = Sequelize;
}
```

Comment: What is the point to declare a module as a string? I haven't seen that before.

Comment: That's a node module.

Comment: I'm confused. One does not use import statements when working with internal modules. The `<reference>` comment should be enough. What if you simply remove `import Sequelize = require("sequelize");` line?

Comment: I know, but you see the `declare module "sequelize"`. How can I reuse that? I get `Sequelize.Model is not defined` or something like that.